# How to handle the fact that Dialog background in Theme.Light are black on pre-ICS sdk and white on ICS

Tags: android, background, dialog, fragmentation

In my application, I use some dialogs to display information.
The theme of my application is Theme.Light since 2 years, and these dialogs have always been black since the beginning.

Now with ICS, it seems that Google just changed his mind and turned these dialogs into white:

See the screenshot of my Moto Xoom and my Galaxy Nexus:

[image]

What is the best practice to handle that true fragmentation?

I have been thinking about creating different layout: layout-v14 but I will soon become crazy, if I have to create layout-v15,v-16, etc for the future?

Or is there a way to tell "lower than v14" and "higher than v14"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

layout-v14 apply to v14 and higher, so if any different style will appear in future you able to add layout-vXX to support this. And all versions between v14 and vXX will apply v14 layout.